# Duda con receptores en Django

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Tengo una duda en cuanto a señales en `Django`.

> Según la documentación de `Django` hay dos maneras de conectar un receptor a una señal en `Django`, la primera que seria con el método `connect()`- (`Signal.connect()`) y la segunda manera, que seria alternativamente a usar, seria un decorador `receiver()`

Mi pregunta es ¿Cual es mejor opción utilizar? y ¿Cuales son las ventajas y desventajas de utilizar la respectiva opción, ya sea con el método `connect()` o con el decorador `receiver()`?

En mi opinión seria mejor opción la segunda manera, con el decorador `receiver()`, específicamente por la sintaxis que se tiene que utilizar para llevarlo a cabo.

La única diferencia que encuentro entre utilizar el método 1 o 2 es la sintaxis, no mas.
Por eso tengo mi duda.

---

***De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si miras la implementación del decorador `receiver` ([aqui](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L272)):

```
def receiver(signal, **kwargs):
    """
    A decorator for connecting receivers to signals. Used by passing in the
    signal (or list of signals) and keyword arguments to connect::
        @receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
        def signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            ...
        @receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=MyModel)
        def signals_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            ...
    """
    def _decorator(func):
        if isinstance(signal, (list, tuple)):
            for s in signal:
                s.connect(func, **kwargs)
        else:
            signal.connect(func, **kwargs)
        return func
    return _decorator
```

vemos algo interesante.

Si el parámetro que pasas al decorador es una sola señal, se limita a usar `signal.connect()` para registrar como receptor la función decorada (código tras el `else:`), por lo que en este caso es totalmente equivalente a `.connect()`.

Pero si le pasas una lista o tupla de señales, entonces iterará por ella y registrará la función decorada como receptor para cada señal de esa lista (código tras `if isinstance()...`)